# Populate Picklist in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In a Lightning Component, I have a custom `Claim__c` object with a picklist field `BillingStage__c`.

I'm trying to initialize an `<aura:attribute name="stages" type="String[]"/>` with the picklist values.

The existing examples I can find use `getDescribe()` off some sObject type, but I can't seem to be able to find something that implements a `getDescribe()` method from inside my component's controller code.

Does anyone know how to pull the existing picklist values for a specific field on a custom object from inside a component controller/helper function?

I haven't been able to find any valid code to populate a picklist in a Lightning component controller, so here's what I think the component would look like:

### foo.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="StageBarApexController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="claim" type="Claim__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="stages" type="String[]"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="this" action="{!c.onInit}"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!stages}" var="stage">
        <p>{!stage}</p>
    </aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

### fooController.js

```
({
    onInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var stages = []; // accumulate picklist values here
        // Existing sample code shows accessing the getDescribe() method on a Schema rooted expression, or a ClassName rooted expression.  For instance in the Using Dynamic Apex to retrieve Picklist Values[1] blog, has:
        var ple = Claim__c.BillingStage__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues(); /*problem*/
        // Fails because Claim__c is not defined.

        // So... What is available to populate a list of picklist values from here?
        // I suspect, nothing but a call out to a custom Apex data controller will work.  But, that creates multiple round-trip server calls. :-(

        component.set("v.stages", stages); // sure wish stages had something in it...
    }
})
```

[1]: [Using Dynamic Apex to retrieve Picklist Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-metadata-api-to-retrieve-picklist-values.html)

Comment: Retrieve them in your Apex controller, and then pass them to your Javascript controller. The general pattern is to use your server-side controller (Apex) to interact with data/metadata in your SFDC org

Comment: Also, unrelated, but I'd recommend getting in the habit of accepting an answer if you feel it answered your question, as it will encourage thoughtful responses to your future questions. I see in your post history that you tend to not do this

Comment: @Brian, thanks for reminding me to go accept answers.  Unfortunately, I haven't had a lot of success getting answers so far.  But, I'll review my posts today and accept anything that actually works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I use it for a lightning component.  I actually have a custom picklist component that I use to populate values and reuse it frequently as I built this before lightning:inputField.  However, it will NOT honor picklist values available for a record type.

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getPicklistOptions(String fieldName, String sObjectName)
    {
        List<String> options = new List<String>();

        // Get describe of all the objects
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        // Get the SObject Type from the specific object name that is passed in
        Schema.SObjectType sobjType = gd.get(sObjectName);
        // Get the describe result of the passed in object
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = sobjType.getDescribe();
        // Get the fields of the passed in object
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> field_map = r.fields.getMap();
        // get the pick list values of the field that was passed in from the field map of the object passed in
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = field_map.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getPickListValues();

        for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : pick_list_values) 
        {
            options.add(f.getLabel());
        }

        system.debug('Options: ' + options);
        return options;
    }
```

Comment: See [my implementation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211420) for a much faster version of what you've written.

Comment: Awesome @sfdcfox  Thanks!  Always looking for better and faster ways!